# $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} |a_k-a_{k+1}|$ converges implies $\lim_{k\to \infty}|a_1 - a_k|$ converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

> $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} |a_k-a_{k+1}|$ converges implies $|a_1 - a_k|$ converges.

I have no idea to proceed the proof. Can anyone give me a hint?

Comment: **Hint:** Triangle inequality

Comment: @Omnomnomnom thanks for your hint. But I only get that |a1-a_k| is bounded using triangle ineq.

Comment: Then you're not using enough triangle inequality

Comment: If a series converges absolutely, it converges

Comment: Show that the sequence $|a_1-a_k|$ is Cauchy

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Thank you so much :))

Comment: @DavidLi: $|a_1 - a_k| = |a_1 - a_2 +a_2 - a_k| < |a_1 -a_2| + |a_2 - a_k|$. Keep repeating this telescoping sum until you get the series which converges.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sequence $(a_n)_n$ is Cauchy:
If $m>n>N$ then $$|a_m-a_n|\le\sum_{k=n}^{m-1}|a_{k+1}-a_k|\le \sum_{k=N}^\infty|a_k-a_{k+1}|$$
and the latter is $<\epsilon$ for $N$ large enough for this expresses exactly that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty|a_k-a_{k+1}| $ converges. Hence with $a:=\lim_{k\to\infty} a_k$, we have $\lim_{k\to\infty}|a_1-a_k|=|a_1-a|$.

Answer (score 2):

$$|(a_1-a_r)-(a_1-a_s)|=|a_r-a_s|= |\sum_{k=r}^{s-1} a_{k+1}-a_k | \le \sum_{k=r}^{s-1} |a_{k+1}-a_k |$$

This is convergent.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that:

$|\sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k-a_{k+1} | = |a_n - a_1 |  \leq \sum_{k=1}^{n} |a_k-a_{k+1}|$ for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: Why is there a $N$ in your answer -- this is true for all $n \geq 1$ by the triangle inequality, after you correct the mismatch in indices (it is $a_{n+1}$, not $a_n$, after the equality.)

Comment: Sorry. It's problem of answering without reviewing.

Comment: @SomeOne Why does $ |\sum_{k=1}^n (a_k-a_{k+1})| $ converge?

Comment: @DavidLi every finite sum converges

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I have just corrected my question. I need the limit convergent. This only implies that each element is bounded. But this doesn't imply the convergent accept for monotone seq

Comment: The limit is exactly the infinite sum from your question

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I don't think so. Because $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} |a_k-a_{k+1}|$ converge doesn't imply  $|\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k-a_{k+1}|$ converges

Comment: @DavidLi it most certainly does imply exactly that